# How can I extract a substring from the results of a cut command in unix?

Tags: unix, scripting, awk, cut

I have a file that is '|' delimited. One of the fields within the file is a time stamp. The field is in the following format: `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` I'd like to be able to print to a file unique dates. I can use the cut command (`cut -f1 -d'|' _file_name_ |sort|uniq`) to extract unique dates. However, with the time portion of the field, I'm seeing hundreds of results. After I run the cut command, I'd like to take the substring of the first eleven characters to display unique dates. I tried using an awk command such as:
    `awk ' { print substr($1,1-11) }' | cut -f1 -d'|' _file_name_ |sort|uniq > _output_file_`

I'm having no luck. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a more simple way of extracting the data I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pls. add an example of the output you _get_ so far, and an example of how you _want_ it to look.

Comment: Smith|John|smithj|1234567|8910|Smoe|Joe|2011-03-27 04:04:04|123 Main St|Tampa|FL|33611|


output: `2011-03-27`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're all most there. This is based on the idea that the date time stamp is in field 1.

Edit : changed field to 10, also used -u option to sort instead of sep process with uniq

You don't need the cut, awk will do that for you.

```
awk -F"|" ' { print substr($10,1,11) }'  _file_name_ |sort -u > _output_file_
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer

Comment: What does the `-u` option do?

Comment: you had `| uniq` ; This is an extra process, as sort has the `'-u'` option that does the same thing (while it is sorting the data). However, Given the sort of data you're processing you might find `... | sort | uniq -c` to provide an interesting statistic. The `-c` option to uniq shows your the **count** of records that it found. Then you would see, for example, 2011-03-25 had 5270 accesses, while 201-03-27 only had 10. Depending on what you are doing, that sort of information can be helpful. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

`cut -c1-11` will display characters 1-11 of each input line.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, in the question I set -f to 1. However, the field is actually located in position 10 of a delimited text file. Therefor when I try `cut -f10 -d'|' -c1-11 my_file.txt |sort|uniq` I get an error. "Only one type of list may be specified."

Comment: `cut -f10 -d'|' my_file.txt | cut -c1-11 | sort -u` should do.

Comment: All that of course if you want to avoid `awk`. I second that using it is better than constructing long pipes.

Answer (score 4):

if the date is the first (space separated) field in the file, then the list of unique dates is just:

```
cut -f1 -d' ' filename | sort -u
```

Update: in addition to @shellter's correct answer, I'll just present an alternative to demonstrate other awk facilities:

```
awk '{split($10, a); date[a[1]]++} END {for (d in date) print d}' filename
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, please see the comment under the first answer. The position of the field is not at the beginning of the line.